# Add sample total num at x-axis for each box at boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I can do it with classic `boxplot`. Here we use the built-in data: `PlantGrown` as example.

```
attach(PlantGrowth)    
boxplot(weight~group,data=PlantGrowth,xaxt="n")
PlantGrowthSum=ddply(PlantGrowth,.(group),summarise,sum=length(weight))

> PlantGrowthSum
   group sum
1  ctrl  10
2  trt1  10
3  trt2  10

axis(1,1:3,paste(PlantGrowthSum$group,"(",PlantGrowthSum$sum,")",sep=""))
```

[image: Boxplot with sum number for each box]

Here is a question, how about `ggplot2`?

```
library(ggplot2)
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group))
    + geom_boxplot()
    +theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
    +theme(axis.text.x=1:3)
bp
```

But it failed. Any clues about which parameter should be set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in this case x values are discrete, you should use `scale_x_discrete()` to set labels for the x axis.

```
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group))+
geom_boxplot()
bp+scale_x_discrete(labels=paste(PlantGrowthSum$group,"(",PlantGrowthSum$sum,")",sep=""))
```

[image]

More information and example about scales and other elements of ggplot2 plot can be found in ggplot2 documentation [site](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/index.html).

Comment: Is the size of the whiskers calculated differently?

Comment: @gd047 Yes, they are calculated differently - see discussion on [ggplot2 mail list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/CWweVZ1vTV4)